# Auto update date-time in QGIS

Tags: date, datetime

In QGIS 3.10 I need something to auto update a datetime attribute.
I need it to update only when any other attribute is updated.

I have tried the following:

Steps:

1. Add a Edited Date Field (ESRI uses EDITED_DT). Make it a Date format.
2. Add a Created Date Field (ESRI uses CREATE_DT). make it a Date format.
3. In Layer Properties Select Attribute Form then the Edited Date field.
4. Towards the bottom change the defaults for the field to now() and apply the default value on update.
5. Once again in the Attribute Form, Open up the Created Date field.
6. Towards the bottom change the defaults for the field to now(). Unlike the edited date do not apply the default value on updates.

But this updates the datetime even when the other attributes are not updated.